# Different conditions for different levels in different variables

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, multiple-conditions

I have a data set with many variables and I would like to apply different conditions for different levels in different variables.

```
data<- read.table(text="
                  Group Group2  Census  Volume
FolC    A   1   0
FolC    A   2   0
FolC    A   3   0
FolC    A   7   0
Fol10   B   1   0.2
Fol10   B   2   0.3
Fol10   B   3   0.8
Fol10   B   7   0
Fol40   C   1   0.1
Fol40   C   2   0.1
Fol40   C   3   0.6
Fol40   C   7   0
FloC    D   1   0.1
FloC    D   2   0.2
FloC    D   3   0.2
FloC    D   7   0.1
Flo10   E   1   0.3
Flo10   E   2   0
Flo10   E   3   1
Flo10   E   7   0
                  
                  ", header=T); head(data); tail(data)
```

I have the following variables: Group (string), Group2 (string), Census (numeric),...
What I need is select at the same time:
a) the rows with Census equal to "3" in Group equal to "Fol10"
b) the rows with Census equal to "2" in Group equal to "Flo10"
I have tried some different codes. I added the last one below.

```
data2<- data %>%
  select(Group, Group2,Census,Volume) %>%
  filter((Group %in% "Fol10" & Census = 3)  | 
        (Group %in% "Flo10" & Census = 2)); data2
```

I would like to have a result like

```
  Group Group2 Census Volume
1 Fol10      B      3    0.8
2 Flo10      E      2    0.0
```

Comment: Well, this seems like a working code to me so I don't understand what is wrong. If you could share a sample of `data`, the output that your get, and the output that you want, then we might be able to help you. BTW, you could replace `%in%` by `==` for the same result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just updated the question and add some data and how I would like the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

result <- data %>% 
    filter(Group == "Fol10" & Census ==  3 | Group == "Flo10" & Census ==  2)

result

#  Group Group2 Census Volume
#1 Fol10      B      3    0.8
#2 Flo10      E      2    0.0
```

We can also use base R as -

```
subset(data, Group == "Fol10" & Census ==  3 | Group == "Flo10" & Census ==  2)
```